# What would be the best way to have a two column transform in a column with a background image?

Tags: css, vue.js, tailwind-css

For example, I would like to have a two column hero section where the first column would be a title/subtitle/action and the second an image, but when going responsive for a smaller screen size, instead of making one on top of another, I would like them to overlap, so that the image is behind now the title/subtitle/action instead of bellow.

I was thinking of something like:

```
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 bg-image">
  <div class="grid-span-2 md:grid-span-1 md:mr-auto">
    // Title
    // Subtitle
    // Action Button
  </div>
</div>
```

But that would make the image always on top of the div, instead of a column like on desktop sizes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by playing with image positionning and z-index when the small screen breakpoint is reached :

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div1">Foo</div>
  <div class="div2">Bar</div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}
.container > div {
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
.div1 {
  background-color : #f00;
  z-index: 2;
}
.div2 {
  background-color : #0f0;
  z-index: 1;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .div2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
  }    
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/bhksd1yn/